# Add class "active" to iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick

My problem is the the script doesnt'work nether the onclick or mousedown. Some time is working but after i wait for ~5 sec (like script take long to load).

My index for the script order , also i am using ajax.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> CV</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">       
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <a href="#home" class="logo" data-scroll>#Antonis</a> 
  <nav class="nav-collapse">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#home" data-scroll>Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#projects" data-scroll>Projects</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#skills" data-scroll>Skills</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#contact" data-scroll>Contact</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="image/bg1.jpg" download="proposed_file_name" data-scroll><span><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>CV</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>


    <div id="view"></div

    <!-- default !-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/onclick.js"></script>

    <!-- Nav bar !-->
    <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>


</body>
```

`$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#projects_view").on('click', ".container", function() {
        $(".myframe").addClass(".active");

        });})`

or
`$(".container").click(function(){
        $(".myframe").toggle("slow");
    });`

and the html with iframe display:none, in css i have a class

.active{display:block;}

```
<div id="projects_view">

<div class="title"><a>Projects</a></div>
    <?php
                                while($record=mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects_recordset)){
                            ?>
        <div class="container col33">
            <img src="./image/projects/project_<?=$record['projects_id']?>.png" alt="preview" class="image">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="project-name"><?=$record['projects_name']?></p>
                        <p class="project-tag"><?=$record['projects_tag']?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error I see is the HTML structure error in your first line of HTML.
You've opened a `<div` and without the closing `>`, you open another div.

Secondly, you are not adding the class `active`, but you are adding the class `.active`, which is probably why your iframe isn't being show.

Try to indent your code, it makes it more readable and a lot easier to spot the errors.

So change

```
$(".myframe").addClass(".active");
```

to

```
$(".myframe").addClass("active");
```

#### edit

I've put your code into a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/25pshb1w/

It's working for me.

Comment: i didn't saw the div thanks! I have change the .active to active. but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Antonisem i've editted my post to include a jsfiddle demo of your code, if you click the text, the iframe shows.

Comment: I have tested the link that you provied but when i copy pasted, it doesn't work even in jsfiddle(the same with your.). Also i tryied the $(".myframe").toggle("slow"); , but nothing ! Did you add something else to jsfiddle?

Comment: @Antonisem It's probably because you're not loading jQuery into the jsfiddle. In the JavaScript pane, on the top right, open the menu and select jQuery as extra script. Try again then

Comment: ok! i have tested a lot of code. now it's working in jsfiddle. But i can't understand why isn't in my project... My script order. From top to bottom before </body>. google api jquery,onclick.js that contains the script that you correct me

Comment: @Antonisem there must be a difference between the fiddle and your project and without more code/info, there is no way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved like this!

```
$(document).on('click', ".container", function() {
    $(".myframe").addClass(".active");
```

' Because the element with class container load after the document ready!
    Thank you'